# correct way to store information to file when application shutdown

Tags: c#

One of my class collects statistics during application execution and I want to store this statistics to disk when application finished. I never destroy this class inside my program so I have tried to store logs to file like that:

```
    ~Strategy()
    {
        foreach(var item in statisticItems)
        {
            log.WriteLine(item.Text);    // log is AutoFlush
        }
    }
```

However I do not see logs I expect to see and also I can not "catch" in debugger moment when destructor called.

Questions:

- Why In debugger I can not catch moment when destructor is called? Isn't destructor must be called for every object when program finishes?
- What should I use to log my stuff?

Comment: Are you shutting down the debugger with the stop button by any chance?

Comment: @Blindy no I just close the window

Comment: Is `Strategy` instantiated? Is it a static class (or are you using only its static methods)? Give us more info, use cases, anything you can. You can discount a bug in the framework for your issue, it's something in your code, and we can only guess at this point.

Comment: @Blindy does it mean that destructor must be always called and destructor is recomended place to do things I do? Yes `Strategy` is insatiated, I use it's instance methods, it's console application.

Comment: Destructors should always be called (unless you encounter insanely catastrophic conditions), but whether or not it's the right place to write your logs is up to you.

Comment: @Blindy: No it's not up to you. It is never a good idea to reference any managed object in the destructor.

Comment: @KendallFrey, I really don't agree with you if you phrase it like that, the GC won't release objects that are referenced by other objects. In this case, his `Strategy` holds a handle to the log. It *will* be valid in the destructor.

Comment: @Blindy: It will exist, but is not necessarily valid, and should be assumed to be invalid. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/11364907/785745

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The destructor (or finalizer) is not the place to put code like that. It is designed for releasing unmanaged resources. Destructors are called non-deterministically, so you can't rely on any of your objects being valid inside the destructor. And you can't catch it in the debugger because it is called on a separate thread, under very special circumstances. In short, do not use destructors, unless you know you need to.

The ideal way to log application shutdown is to simply place the logging code at the end of the `Main` method. You should make sure that you catch and log any exceptions that are thrown, and if that is the case, you can log the shutdown at the end of `Main`.

There will be a few edge cases where you won't be able to log the shutdown, because of errors such as a stack overflow. In those cases, you will need to rely on logs of what happened before the error.

Comment: It answers the question "What should I use to log my stuff?"

Comment: It now addresses the other question as well.

Answer (score -1):

Dont rely on destructors.  I would recommend using something like this:

```
[STAThread]
static void Main()
{
    using(new Strategy())
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }
}

public class Strategy : IDisposable
{
    public void Dispose()
    {
        WriteLogs()
    }
    ...
}
```

This way you are sure that your logs will be written.

The static void Main is copied from the default program.cs that is created when creating a windows forms application.

Comment: -1 for promoting the wrong disposable pattern. You shouldn't mess with this one, use the real deal.

Comment: Why are you using `STAThread` attribute which belongs to COM afaik? why shouldn't I rely on destructor?

Comment: `Disposable` is an optimization over destructors (and the proper pattern includes a destructor anyway), its main benefit is that it allows you to release resources on demand.

Comment: @Blindy in my case I want to avoid "on demand". I just want to store everything when program finishes.

Answer (score -1):

This is **not a complete answer** (yet), but check this out:

> The programmer has no control over when the destructor is called
>   because this is determined by the garbage collector. The garbage
>   collector checks for objects that are no longer being used by the
>   application. If it considers an object eligible for destruction, it
>   calls the destructor (if any) and reclaims the memory used to store
>   the object. Destructors are also called when the program exits.

Source: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/66x5fx1b.aspx)

If it's a console app, could you try calling `Environment.Exit(0);` to see what happens?

Let's keep this answer updated, as this is an interesting question. Anyone feel free to edit.

Regards

Comment: If you want a wiki-style answer, a community wiki answer is the way to go.

Comment: @KendallFrey if you do not want to edit, you don't have to. Still, I've made a question to the OP and I'm waiting on the feedback to improve my answer. Better than just saying "you are wrong, should do this way"

Comment: The comments are the place to ask questions of the OP. The answers are for answers.

Comment: @KendallFrey That's funny. Aren't comments for... comments? What are you up to, browsing around and whinning that everyone is wrong? I'm trying to give an answer to this question, give a break.

Comment: I'm not saying you're wrong. I'm only trying to help you. I have nothing against the content of your answer. I just pointed out how the question/comment/answer system works.