# mysterious array keeps reference to object in unit tests

Tags: c#, unit-testing, garbage-collection, xunit.net

I just observed a really weird behavior in Visual Studio 2013 Update 4. Consider the following xunit.net test:

```
[Fact]
public void TestTargetMustNotHoldAReferenceToItemsAfterCallingClear()
{
    var item = new MarkedType();
    var weakReferenceToItem = new WeakReference<MarkedType>(item);
    var testTarget = new ListBuilder<MarkedType>().WithItems(item)
                                                  .Build();

    testTarget.Clear();

    item = null;
    GC.Collect();
    MarkedType retrievedItem = null;
    Assert.False(weakReferenceToItem.TryGetTarget(out retrievedItem));
    Assert.Null(retrievedItem);
}

public class MarkedType { }
```

In it, I want to check that my own `List<T>` implementation does not hold references to objects on the heap after I call `Clear` on it. Therefore I set `item` to `null` after the call to `Clear` and let the Garbage Collector run so that it can deallocate the `MarkedType` instance. Afterwards I check with a weak reference that the instance is really gone.

**Here is the weird thing:** this test does not pass in Debug mode in VS 2013 Update 4 with xunit.net v2.0.0 prerelease because `WeakReference.TryGetTarget` returns `true`. **However, if I switch to Release mode, this test passes.** I also ran this test in VS 2015 CTP6 and there it passes in both configurations, Debug and Release.

I then created two memory dumps (one before the garbage collector run, one after) to figure out what object keeps `item` in memory and I found an object array that is not listed in my test:

[image: Marked Type Path To Root]

**My actual questions are: where does this object array come from? Why isn't it present in Release mode (or VS 2015)? Can I somehow disable or circumvent it?**

If you want to play around with the source code, it is available on github (please use the FailingReferenceTest branch): https://github.com/feO2x/BeginningTdd

Comment: This problem smacks of the idea that `GC.Collect` should be immediate, when in fact [it is not](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11354128/2589202)

Comment: I would say that `MarkedType` has no destructor and thus is deallocated in one garbage collector run.

Comment: Not only is `GC.Collect()` not immediate, but per the Remarks on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xe0c2357(v=vs.110).aspx), *objects that are referenced in managed code are not collected*.  You may want to look into using [GCSettings.LargeObjectHeapCompactionMode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.gcsettings.largeobjectheapcompactionmode(v=vs.110).aspx), it would be at least worth a try.

Comment: Add `GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers()` after `GC.Collect()` and give that a try.

Comment: I tried both `GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers` and `GC.WaitForFullGCComplete` - none of them worked. And by the way, this wouldn't explain why it works in Release mode (or in VS 15 CTP 6). Maybe it has something to do with the .NET / CLR version?