# C# Memory leak query - Why GC is not releasing memory of the local scope?

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Before 1st call TestFunc");
        TestFunc();
        Console.WriteLine("After 1st call TestFunc");
        Console.WriteLine("Before 2nd call TestFunc");
        TestFunc();
        Console.WriteLine("After 2nd call TestFunc");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static void TestFunc()
    {
        List<Employee> empList = new List<Employee>();
        for (int i = 1; i <= 50000000; i++)
        {
            Employee obj = new Employee();
            obj.Name = "fjasdkljflasdkjflsdjflsjfkldsjfljsflsdjlkfajsd";
            obj.ID = "11111111111111112222222222222222222222222222222";
            empList.Add(obj);
        }
    }
}

public class Employee
{
    public string Name;
    public string ID;
}
```

I am creating lot of employees only inside a location(local scope), when the control comes back to main function, why DOTNET is not releasing the memory?
Lets say each function call is using 1 GB of memory, at the end of the function main, still the application uses more than 1Gb of memory. Why GC is not collecting after the scope goes off?

This might be a simple question, Any help would be great.

Comment: You have not given enough information to allow us to properly understand your scenario. Your example code clearly does not correlate what you try to explain ("control comes back to main function"???). Note that the GC only runs "when it feels like" (i.e. due to memory pressure or other circumstances that trigger the GC). Also note that there are two different heaps used by .NET program: the small object heap and the large object heap (LOH). The LOH is used for objects which are larger than 84KB or so (large arrays, very long strings, etc...). (1/2)

Comment: (2/2) Contrary to the small object heap, the large object heap does not automatically shrink when the GC erases objects from it, depending on circumstances (see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035550/large-object-heap-compaction-when-is-it-good , https://www.wintellect.com/hey-who-stole-all-my-memory/). So, if your program uses the LOH a lot, you might need to comact it at appropriate times (see the link i gave). There is of course also the possibility that the data in your program has not been GCed because some other part of your program still holds references to it. I don't know.

Comment: If you are concerned about memory leak you can call GC.Collect() with GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers(). Please check here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11354086/gc-collect-not-collecting-immediately Let your object with cleaned up before next call

Comment: @ManishM, calling GC.Collect() with GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers() will not fix suspected memory/resource leaks (in the usual sense of memory/resource leak). It can be a crude hack-ish attempt to release resources _earlier_ / _quicker_, but it can't fix leaks...

Comment: Don't *assume* a memory leak. A decent profiler will tell you if you're leaking objects and help you work out how they're "rooted" (what's keeping them alive). The goal of GC is *not* to free memory. It's to pretend that [infinite amounts of memory exist](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20100809-00/?p=13203).

Comment: thanks for the inputs. Obviously the above memory is allocated in LargeObjectHeap. To compress the large object heap,  we have to call 
    GCSettings.LargeObjectHeapCompactionMode = 
    GCLargeObjectHeapCompactionMode.CompactOnce;
    GC.Collect();     My question is, I am not leaking memory here, GC supposed to collect the memory, but its not happening even during the end of main. If I do GC.Collect, GC is releasing the LOH memory.

Comment: @raj - the point is though, that it's **not** considered to be a memory leak if the GC *could* free the memory now if it chose to run but it has currently not decided to run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GC doesn't start automatically at the end of scope or function call. According to MS documentation:

Garbage collection occurs when one of the following conditions is true:

•The system has low physical memory. This is detected by either the low memory notification from the OS or low memory indicated by the host.

•The memory that is used by allocated objects on the managed heap surpasses an acceptable threshold. This threshold is continuously adjusted as the process runs.

•The GC.Collect method is called. In almost all cases, you do not have to call this method, because the garbage collector runs continuously. This method is primarily used for unique situations and testing.

[Fundamentals of Garbage Collection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/fundamentals)