# memory leak in a c# api

Tags: c#, asp.net, memory-leaks, pomelo-entityframeworkcore-mysql

Even with a very simple request my c# api gets filled with unnecessary byte[] strings etc. and i really can't find anywhere where i think there can be a memory leak.

***a little description:***
The method collects all notebooks from a user and returns them.
It recognizes the user by the BearerToken.

***Here is the code that is called, and yet per request several kb more ram is consumed and never released:***

**GetCurrentUser:**

```cs
public static async Task<UserModel?> GetCurrentUser(DataBaseContext _db, string bearerToken)
{
    //get from the bearer token the username
    //create jwt token
    var token = new JwtSecurityToken(jwtEncodedString: bearerToken);

    //get the expiry from the token
    var userName = token.Claims.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier)?.Value;

    //get the whole user form the db
    var user = _db.User
        .Include(x => x.Invoices)
        .Include(x => x.Notebook)
        .Include(x => x.Logins)
        .FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Username == userName);

    return await user;
}
```

**GetCurrentUser & GetAll**

```cs
private async Task<UserModel?> GetCurrentUser()
{
    // Get the bearer token from the header
    var bearerToken = HttpContext.Request.Headers["bearerToken"].ToString();
    var user = await UserCore.GetCurrentUser(_db, bearerToken);
    return user;
}

[HttpGet]
[Route("GetAll")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetAll()
{
    //set the users traceId
    Guid traceId = Guid.NewGuid();
            
    //get the user
    var user = await GetCurrentUser();
    if (user == null)
        return new BadRequestObjectResult(ResponseMgr.CreateResponse(400, traceId, "The user does not exist"));

    //get all notes
    var notes = user.Notebook.ToList();
    
    //return all notes
    return new OkObjectResult(ResponseMgr.CreateResponse(200, traceId, "All notes", new Dictionary<string, object> { { "notes", notes } }));
}
```

***this is the heapmap:***
[image: mem usage]

[image: heapmap]

this is one of the things i don't understand, this is the list with "duplicate strings", first column says "value", second "wasted" and third "count" and at the bottom "total"

The thing is, the emojis are content/value of one the notebook, but why does it keep the data and not release them after the request, so to sum up I found the leak but not where it happens.
[image: double chars]

All in one, I can't find the location, and if I make the request 50 times, then the API consumes several MB of ram and they will release the even the GC can't do that.

Comment: If there is indeed a memory leak, then if you run your program long enough it will consume all available memory and your system will start responding very slowly. Likely what's happening is that the GC sees that there's still memory available and no other applications are asking for any, so it doesn't see any particular reason to run. If you run your program long enough, the GC will probably kick in before things get out of hand.

Comment: as far as I know the GC doesn't work like that, it would be stupid to run something like that on an AWS server. 
My question remains, why does data from a completed request remain in the heap, even if the GC was triggered.

Comment: two hunches.. 
1. Make ```GetCurrentUser``` a non-static method - I am suspecting lifetime scope issues may be
2. After you get all notes, try setting the user variable to null
```var notes = user.Notebook.ToList();
  user = null; 
```

Comment: It's not stupid, that's how GC works. Please read up about GC, it works based on memory pressure. If the AWS server is not giving memory pressure then it has no reason to run a collection and release memory.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# Memory leak query - Why GC is not releasing memory of the local scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52234689/c-sharp-memory-leak-query-why-gc-is-not-releasing-memory-of-the-local-scope)

Comment: @Sekhar : Object in c# contain a counter for external links.  The GC does not remove an item unless the external link count is zero.  The code is calling the constructor with new which is creating a external link to the objects.  So you have two link to "object".  The object and the OkObjectResult().

Comment: @Charlieface If the GC really waits until hell burns, then you can forget about the GC directly.
Just because a server has e.g. 64gb ram, a program must not take 36gb ram although he would need only fractions. 

Actually (according to my knowledge), if I leave e.g. "GetAll()", then everything inside is no longer allocated and the GC if the is triggered, finds the data and will release that.

Comment: You might want to tweak the GC options https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/runtime-config/garbage-collector

Comment: @jdweng: that's not how the GC works; there's no reference counting in GC-land. Instead, roots are traced to determine if objects are referenced or not. GC-managed programs nearly all look like they have memory leaks if you just look at current heap usage. Instead, open _Performance Monitor_ (aka _PerfMon_) and use the _.NET Memory Counters_ to see what's going on. You can see _Gen0_, _Gen1_ and _Gen2_ collections and get a much better view of the _Managed Heap_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. your code have another problem too. when `username` null, not need check it the query for `null` member just need forexample return it the `null`
2. you use more `.Include()`, If one of them is a large amount of data, you will have problems (you return `List` items, try take there data with another and better query )
3. use `AsNoTracking()`

   means:

> returns a new query and the entities aren't saved in cache, means that
> doesn't have tracking, the queries will read from database origin but
> won't saved in the context

Comment: Thanks for your help, regarding 2, yes you are right, this I also changed directly & regarding 3, it sounds logical but it still stored it in the cache, or could find it in the heap again. Thanks for "2" though.